# Window Closing Issues In Ajax

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

In codeigniter application i pop up a window from a view page using href link.In that pop up window there have a button to close window after done process.

I want to refresh the view page after closing the pop up window when i clicking on the button in the pop up window.How can i do that?Is there any way to solve my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have the close button call this javascript:

```
if ( window.opener && !window.opener.closed ) {
    window.opener.location.reload();
}
```

This will test that the opening window exists and is not closed, and then try to reload it.

You could also access other functions or variables using `window.opener` if you wanted to call some other function, or make it a little more dynamic by only changing one part of the page.

Comment: where i write this script? In the pop up window?

Comment: Yeah, add it to the javascript of the pop-up window, called when you click the close button.